# RubyMotion, getting has one window [FAILED - 2.==(1) failed] when I run default test

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

Wondering if anyone is having or had this issue, I just ran the default test generated with RubyMotion's **rake spec**

```
describe "Application 'UIAlert'" do                                                                                            
 before do
   @app = UIApplication.sharedApplication
 end

 it "has one window" do
   @app.windows.size.should == 1
 end
end
```

It fails with this error:

```
Application 'UIAlert'
 - has one window [FAILED - 2.==(1) failed]

Bacon::Error: 2.==(1) failed
  spec.rb:769:in `satisfy:': Application 'UIAlert' - has one window
  spec.rb:783:in `method_missing:'
  spec.rb:316:in `block in run_spec_block'
  spec.rb:459:in `execute_block'
  spec.rb:316:in `run_spec_block'
  spec.rb:331:in `run'
```

I am not sure how could my app could possibly have more than one window, something I am missing? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the iOS8 SDK? iOS8 introduced UITextEffectsWindow - this gets created in addition to the application window so @app.windows.size == 2 and not 1. You can check this by running your app and in the REPL looking at the 2 window objects.

```
(main)> UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows[0]
=> #<UIWindow:0x11280d700>
(main)> UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows[1]
=> #<UITextEffectsWindow:0x10b6127a0>
```

I would suggest modifying the default spec to one which tests that the application window has a default rootViewController for example.

Comment: This was indeed the case, solved my curiosity. Thanks.